# Capybara does not find element properly on Edge

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, microsoft-edge

I have encountered an issue that really makes me confused. I'm able to find elements on a page but after I interact with elements from bottom of page, I cannot  click element that are on top of page without scrolling to top of page. This only happens on Edge browser (Chrome, Firefox work well).

My code is as below:

```
page.fill_in_form # This part is middle/bottom of page
page.click_button 'SAVE' # This button is middle/bottom of page
page.select_sub_menu 'Category' #This sub menu is top navigation of page
```

And this is error message.

```
Unable to find css "#subnav"
```

My select_sub_menu funciton:

```
def select_sub_menu(sub_menu)
    within('#subnav') { click_link(sub_menu) }
end
```

It looks like Capybara does not recognise the elements are on top of page after scrolling into middle of page although they are available.

My driver is configured as below:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Edge.driver_path = "#{file_path}/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I use Microsoft Web Driver version: 6.17134.

Comment: Please provide code that shows exactly what you're doing and the exact error you get - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, I have edited the content of question. I'm not sure if I provide enough information.

Comment: Have you checked `page.html` to make sure what you think is on the page actually is?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I have checked page.html and noticed that it still includes <nav id="subnav">.